# CSV Data Set Config is not passing variables for scripts where the Method is POST

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Receiving a Bad Request whenever I'm trying to run a Jmeter script with a variable value and the method is `POST`

All of the scripts with method as `GET` are running fine

Receiving the below response:

> For request 'POST /api/v1/getAllWorkbooks' [Invalid Json: Unrecognized token '$email': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: [B@51770ad6; line: 1, column: 17]]

Can someone please help me with the jmeter configuration for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `${email} within ${}`. I hope that you are reading from CSV.

Comment: Tried that right now. Still failing. Yes I'm reading from CSV. CSV File has the following Data: OpenX,CPR,sundeep.kumar@openx.com and the variables are org,view,email. The reponse I got this time for ${view} was For request 'POST /api/v1/getUserAccessList' [Invalid Json: Unrecognized token &#x27;OpenX&#x27;: was expecting (&#x27;true&#x27;, &#x27;false&#x27; or &#x27;null&#x27;)
 at [Source: [B@3eda1e18; line: 1, column: 23]]

Comment: It worked. Had to put the ${email} within "". Like "${email}". Thanks Though

Comment: see JMeter variable substitution requires to use within ${}. Quotes are needed for your API to run. So if in JSON "email" : "a@a.com" is required you need to place "${email}" in quotes, otherwise not.